# how to change image file rotation status without loading it into memory

Tags: c#, winforms, jpeg, exif

Someone told me some image file like jpg just use some bits to control the rotation status.

Is there any way to change this status without loading the picture file to main memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to mark a JPG file to change how it is supposed to be displayed without loading and decoding the JPG image into an in-memory bitmap.  The JPG image file can optionally include an EXIF metadata section, often used to describe the device and circumstances involved in the creation or capture of the image - Camera model, shutter speed, ISO exposure equivalent, etc.

The EXIF metadata also includes an Orientation flag which can be used to inform image viewer apps how the pixels of the JPG image should be oriented on the display surface.  This orientation flag (and the EXIF metadata) can be read and written in the JPG file without loading or decoding the pixel image data.  This also means that orientation can be changed multiple times without loss of image detail, since the image is not being decompressed, rotated, and then recompressed into a new file on disk.

To do this, you will need C# code that will read the JFIF file format of the JPG file and find and extract the EXIF section.  I don't think the built-in .NET Image reader provides anything like that.

Note that not all JPG readers honor the EXIF orientation flag.  I believe the Windows built-in Image Preview app respects the EXIF orientation flag in current versions of Windows, but it did not in earlier Windows versions such as Windows XP.

More info on the EXIF orientation flag here: http://jpegclub.org/exif_orientation.html

Comment: but to see the image actually rotated you would need that the viewer obeys this Orientation flag... how many viewers actually do that?

Comment: I find the Orientation flag is now more often supported by a viewer than not.  The Windows Vista and Windows 7 Image Preview honor the Orientation flag.  When you are viewing an image in the Previewer and you change its orientation, it does so with no loss of image detail - which to me, sounds like it's modifying the EXIF orientation flag.  I suspect the .NET Image class may honor the Orientation flag when loading a JPG file into an in-memory bitmap but I haven't tested it.